# spark: How to read json list without StructField?

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Some ETL jobs need to read json like:

```
[{"f1":1, "f2":2}, {"f1":10, "f2":20}, {"f1":4, "f2":8}]
[{"f1":3, "f2":5}]
[{"f1":7, "f2":9}, {"f1":111, "f2":2}]
```

Each line of input files is a json list.
But, `schema` for `spark.read.json` have to be StructType. 
How to read this kind of json list without StructField to a DataFrame with a specified `schema` ?

Comment: Why are you worried about the schema? Why don't you let the JSON reader infer the schema automatically? Use `inferSchema` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can just do:

```
spark.read
  .json("src/test/resources/test.json")
  .show()
```

which prints:

```
+---+---+
| f1| f2|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
| 10| 20|
|  4|  8|
|  3|  5|
|  7|  9|
|111|  2|
+---+---+
```

where spark's deduced schema is:

```
println(spark.read.json("src/test/resources/test.json").schema)
> StructType(StructField(f1,LongType,true), StructField(f2,LongType,true))
```